# Lubuntu 18.04LTS touchpad config: what file will turn off tapping?

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, touchpad

I have seen numerous posts about touchpad issues, but have mainly seen GUI solutions, such as adding "touchpad-indicator" (which didn't work the way I'd hoped) or synaptics (which froze my keyboard at login requiring a whole reinstall).  I have seen a great tutorial of exactly what I hope to accomplish for 18.10 here: [anglehit](https://anglehit.com/how-to-enable-touchpad-click-on-lubuntu-18-10/)

But the problem is I don't seem to have an xorg.conf.d file in /etc/X11 in Lubuntu 18.04LTS.

I would love to just open a text editor, open a config file, and edit a setting to something like:

```
tapping = "off"
```

Hit save, and be done.  Is there any way to do this on Lubuntu 18.04LTS?

Thank you very much.

Comment: hi your question title says cli and you wrote you want to open a text editor.... can you clarify?

Comment: @PRATAP I think OP want to know if there's a text file that can be modified thereby turning off tapping, whatever that means.

Comment: Maybe something like `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false` ?

Comment: @DKBose I am still thinking the OP mentioned CLI in his Q title.. but when he explained he wrote he want to edit. which is stopping to go further if there are any workarounds for each subject either CLI like you proposed or to create a file which he said didn't find..

Comment: @PRATAP I agree it's quite confusing!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments.  I tried to edit the original to be clearer, but @DKBose, can you tell me where I can find that "org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad" file?  Yes, that's what I'm trying to do, but can't locate that file.  I tried "sudo find / -name "*touchpad*" and didn't find anything...all I need to know is if there's a config file somewhere, and if so, how to correctly change the setting to turn off tapping entirely.

Comment: And apologies for confusing cli with text files.  I've always thought they're synonymous but you guys showed me there's a difference.  @DKBose's solution is something I can type into the command line directly...I thought that was a configuration file that needed editing.  If you post this as a solution I'll mark it correct -- assuming it works.  :-)  But ideally, I'd also like to know where that file is so I could open it and manually adjust settings true or false as I wished.

Comment: And on my system that "org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad" gives me a "file not found" error.  So I guess that's not the solution after all.

Comment: Okay, figured it out:  the full line is "gsettings set..." then the org.gnome...Again, if you care to post as an answer I'd be happy to click solved.  Well, I still need to reboot and make sure this fixed it.  But hopefully it will!  :-)

Comment: Well, alas, that didn't work.  Tap-to-click IS now set to false, but it had no effect, still having the same tapping even after a reboot (and a check that it's still set to false).  So that's not the solution.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: It's lubuntu guys. You can create the file by your own.